# Efficient way to convert delimiter separated string to numpy array

Tags: python, numpy

I have a String as follows :

```
1|234|4456|789
```

I have to convert it into numpy array.I would like to know the most efficient way.Since I will be calling this function for more than 50 million times!

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The fastest way is to use the [numpy.fromstring](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.fromstring.html) method:

```
>>> import numpy
>>> data = "1|234|4456|789"
>>> numpy.fromstring(data, dtype=int, sep="|")
array([   1,  234, 4456,  789])
```

Comment: why didn't i think of that.. :P

Comment: Thank you so much.. Quite efficient from the @bernie time calculation.. :)

Answer (score 8):

[@jterrace](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9816147/42346) wins one (1) internet.

In the measurements below the example code has been shortened to allow the tests to fit on one line without scrolling where possible.

For those not familiar with `timeit` [the `-s` flag allows you to specify a bit of code which will only be executed once](http://docs.python.org/2/library/timeit.html#cmdoption-timeit-s).

---

The fastest and least-cluttered way is to use `numpy.fromstring` as jterrace suggested:

```
python -mtimeit -s"import numpy;s='1|2'" "numpy.fromstring(s,dtype=int,sep='|')"
100000 loops, best of 3: 1.85 usec per loop
```

---

The following three examples use `string.split` in combination with another tool.

`string.split` with `numpy.fromiter`

```
python -mtimeit -s"import numpy;s='1|2'" "numpy.fromiter(s.split('|'),dtype=int)"
100000 loops, best of 3: 2.24 usec per loop
```

`string.split` with `int()` cast via generator-expression

```
python -mtimeit -s"import numpy;s='1|2'" "numpy.array(int(x) for x in s.split('|'))"
100000 loops, best of 3: 3.12 usec per loop
```

`string.split` with NumPy array of type `int`

```
python -mtimeit -s"import numpy;s='1|2'" "numpy.array(s.split('|'),dtype=int)"
100000 loops, best of 3: 9.22 usec per loop
```

Comment: much better explanation on speed difference!

Answer (score 5):

Try this:

```
import numpy as np
s = '1|234|4456|789'
array = np.array([int(x) for x in s.split('|')])
```

... Assuming that the numbers are all ints. if not, replace `int` with `float` in the above snippet of code.

**EDIT 1:**

Alternatively, you can do this, it will only create *one* intermediate list (the one generated by `split()`):

```
array = np.array(s.split('|'), dtype=int)
```

**EDIT 2:**

And yet another way, possibly faster (thanks for all the comments, guys!):

```
array = np.fromiter(s.split("|"), dtype=int)
```

Comment: The problem with this is that it generates an in-memory list of all the parts of the string.  If there really are 50 million parts, that's a lot of extra memory for a temporary list.

Comment: @AdamMihalcin that really depends on the version of Python in use. In Python 3, the list is evaluated lazily and no intermediate lists are created. Also, the OP said that the function would be called 50 million times, not that there are 50 million elements in the list.

Comment: @AdamMihalcin Even if you use `imap` or a generator expression? Oscar - On Python 3, the list comprehension still will create an intermediate list.

Comment: You can simplify it as `array = np.array(s.split('|'), dtype=int)`. But that still leaves you with a large in-memory list.

Comment: @agf `imap` or a generator would indeed be lazy.  But my point is that the list comprehension and plain old `map` posted here would certainly create an intermediate list.

Comment: @AdamMihalcin He's calling the function 50 million times, probably each individual string isn't that long.

Comment: FWIW I find np.fromiter(s.split("|"), dtype=int) is several times faster.

Comment: @AdamMihalcin the OP didn't specify that the _list_ is long, only that the function will get called a lot of times

Comment: True that I iterate 50 million times and the number of elements in the array might be 25 to 30 max!..Thanks a lot guys!