# convert float string to numpy array with different rows

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, string-conversion

I have string `final_line` as

```
0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0130631958731,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0130631958731,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,,
0.00507937313707,0.0,0.0,0.0201058520009,0.0,0.0,0.0459562331449,0.0268078026679,0.0,0.0103772139359,0.0,0.0,0.0438673134565,0.0,0.0268078026679,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0224437417685,,
0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.070802847389,0.0,0.0,,
0.0,0.0,0.169140135429,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,,
0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0261263917462,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0261263917462,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,,
0.0961428138228,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,,
```

I want to convert it into numpy array for without transferring to `CSV` file. Here each line in string should be converted to different row as

```
[['0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0.08364751'], ['0.017944717', '0', '0', '0', '0.009470823', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0'], ['0.012620501', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0'], ['0.012620501', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0'], ['0', '0', '0', '0', '0.01332164', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0'], ['0.012620501', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0'], ['0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0.097414177', '0.042092545', '0', '0', '0', '0'], ['0', '0', '0', '0', '0.01332164', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0'], ['0.005324215', '0', '0', '0.04598186', '0.028100025', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0.023525603'], ['0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0.055765006', '0', '0'], ['0', '0', '0.133216404', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0']]
```

I know here output having different values but I have just shown to get the format

Example

I have string as

```
a1,b1,c1,d1,e1,,
a2,b2,c2,d2,e2,,
a3,b3,c3,d3,e3,,
```

then output should be

```
[['a1','b1','c1','d1','e1'],
 ['a2','b2','c2','d2','e2'],
 ['a3','b3','c3','d3','e3']]
```

I have seen other questions but it converts into only single row of array. Here I want every single line in new row as shown in example.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9815911/efficient-way-to-convert-delimiter-separated-string-to-numpy-array

Comment: Add a reshape to the answer @Robert linked to get a 2D array.  For example, `np.fromstring(final_line, sep=',').reshape(final_line.count(',,')+1, -1)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`map` can be useful in this case. Also, the last `,,` in your `final list` is not necessary so I just ignored it (look at `:-2` before `split` operation).

```
import numpy as np

A = final_line[:-2].split(',,')
B = np.array([map(float,a.split(',')) for a in A])
```

Comment: It gives me `ValueError: could not convert string to float: 
`

Comment: I did exceptional handling. It gives me error on last line of data. It may contain some invisible data because it did problem with `csv` file too.

Comment: yes it gives you the error if your file is not properly formatted

Comment: actually `:-2` removes my invisible data too. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Your data is in the form of lists, with each line separated by an additional comma.

```
d_in = "1,2,3,,4,5,6,,7,8,9"
first = d_in.split(",,")
final = [line.split(",") for line in first]
```

`first` stores a list of strings (each of your columns).  `final` stores your data in the proper format (in my example, `[[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]`)